# How to play MP3 format data in browser?

Tags: php, html5-audio, audio-streaming, file-writing, php-curl

I am using php for server side scripting. In default I am using "audio" tag for playing audio files, Because my api call returns file path so it is easily handle.
for example my example look like this:

```
{
    'id':123,
    'question':'tell about your self?',
    'audio':'/wdk/path/00fl.mp3'
}
```

so i can easily use this in audio tag.`<audio src="www.abc.in/wdk/path/00fl.mp3" preload="auto">`

But now i getting different format of API response. It returns data content instead of url. For example

```
{
    'id':123,
    'question':'tell about your self?',
    'audio':'/wdk/path/MP3'
}
```

so now i need to make curl call again with content-type:audio/mpeg for getting data-content.It returns raw mp3 format data. So how can we play the audio file in browser? is any player there for convert mp3 format data to player data straightly? and i tried another way, but  i could not able to store a mp3 format file in php. 
can we create mp3 file using php? for ex:

```
 $myfile = fopen("D:\xampp\htdocs\abc\testfile.mp3", "w"); 
 $fwrite($myfile, $result);
```

my curl response like this:
ID3#TSSELavf56.15.102��8�Infora
!#%*,.0357<>@BEGIMPRTVY[*adfhjmqsuxz|~��������������������������������������������������Lavc56.13$a5Cwc��8�"#�p7I<��Z���<ѣF� 
��HP���.uN{P�!  �{�����������*]�D�DDwww��������"'����_���";�������=��B""�������

Comment: How is the first sample different than the second?  What are you trying to do?  Why can't you use an audio tag?

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the contents of the mp3 file, you can use data URI, the source is just encoded file contents:

```
echo '<audio src="data:audio/mpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($sound_text).'"  autoplay="autoplay" controls ></audio>';
```

Answer (score 1):

## Data-URI

You *could* use data-URIs as @n-dru suggests in his answer, but you should be aware of a couple of things:

- Base-64 increases the data size by 33%, and strings in JavaScript uses two bytes per char.
- Some browsers limits the maximum data-URIs length (as there is a significant overhead decoding them)

## Blob + ObjectURL

A better approach IMO, is to use Blobs and ObjectURLs. It's not without its own drawbacks though:

- Require CORS fulfillment to load the data for the Blob (ie. your sample data must come from the same server as the page -or- the server must allow CORS usage)
- The URL object must be prefixed in some browsers (incl. webkit)

The advantage is that the data can be loaded and used as a raw byte-buffer with no overhead in decoding nor bandwidth.

### Example

This example loads the MP3 data (which would be the raw data you receive), then creates a Blob and an ObjectURL for the Blob. This can then be set as source for the audio element.

The example also shows how to handle the asynchronous nature of the various stages.

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");

audio.onload = function() {
  // audio has loaded..
  audio.play();
  // continue from here (or the onerror event, not shown)
};

// load the url as raw data and create an ObjectURL:
loadRaw("/wdk/path/MP3", function(url) {
   audio.src = url;
});

function loadRaw(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url);
  xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
  xhr.onerror = function() {console.log("Network error.")};
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: "audio/mpeg"}),
          oURL = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
      callback(oURL);
    }
    else {console.log("Loading error:" + xhr.statusText)}
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```